# How to load html content dynamically with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, requirejs-text

I want to load a html content with RequireJS like this:

```
define(function (require) {

"use strict";

return function (id) {
     var url = 'text!screens/' + id + '.html';
     var html = require(url);
}; });
```

But I get this error: 
**Error: Module name "text!screens/home.html_unnormalized2" has not been loaded yet for context: _**

If I try it in this way:

```
define(function (require) {

"use strict";

return function () {
     var html = require('text!screens/home.html');
}; });
```

everything is ok. But this approach isn't very nice due to hardcore tipped url. How can I solve this?

Comment: How are you using the first code block? (i.e. where is that code that has the `"home"` string?

Comment: It is used as a dependency in another module and there it will be called like a function: load(id).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inline parametric `require` calls can only run asynchronously for modules that have not been loaded yet, as is your case. The principle is (also note `url` is in an array):

```
var url = 'text!screens/' + id + '.html';
require([url],
    function(text) {
        // use text
    },
    function(err) { // OPTIONAL BUT GOOD PRACTICE
        // handle error
    }
);
```

This has the inconvenience of not beign able to return the value immediately. Also take a look at the principle of [promises](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/) (implemented by many libraries, [jQuery too](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)).